# Can't create a NIC using Azure CLI (BadRequestError)

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-cli

Consider the following scenario:

- One resource-group called `rg-foo` which was created in the location `switzerlandnorth`
- One virtual network called `vnet-switzerland-north` holding one subnet called `default` also in the location `switzerlandnorth`
- The mentioned vnet is part of another resource-group called `rg-vnets` which is at `westeurope`

Now I'd like to create a NIC and attach it to subnet `default`. So here is what I did:

```
az network nic create --name nicfoo --subnet default --vnet-name vnet-switzerland-north --resource-group rg-foo
```

Which however results in...

> BadRequestError: Resource
> /subscriptions/subscription-guid/resourceGroups/rg-foo/providers/Microsoft.
> Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-switzerland-north/subnets/default
> referenced by resource
> /subscriptions/subscription-guid/resourceGroups/rg-foo/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nicfoo
> was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists,
> and that both resources are in the same region.

I just can't make any sense out of this error message. Of course the vnet and subnet exists, double and triple checked also their location. Even if I add the `--location` parameter and explicitly state that I want the nic to be in the same region the same error occurs.

Also providing the id like this doesn't make any change.

```
subnetid=$(az network vnet subnet show --vnet-name vnet-switzerland-north --name default --resource-group rg-vnets --output tsv --query [id])
az network nic create --name nicfoo --subnet $subnetid
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Edit**

- Updating to the latest Azure CLI version (2.13.0) didn't make a change
- I am able to create the nic via azure portal without any issues

If I create another test-vnet (@`switzerlandnorth`) and put it into rg-foo (@`switzerlandnorth`) then I am able to create a nic in that rg with the beforementioned parameters. It seems that the Azure CLI doesn't like the fact that `rg-vnets` is in `westeurope`.

---

**Edit**

What's also interesting is that it works with Azure PowerShell.

```
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name vnet-switzerland-north
$subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name default -VirtualNetwork $vnet
$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name nicfoo -ResourceGroupName rg-foo -Subnet $subnet -Location switzerlandnorth
```

Comment: Have you set the correct subscription in the CLI using az account set --subscription <subscriptionId> if you have more than one sub it could be looking at the wrong one

Comment: Thanks for replying. There is only one subscription which is correctly set (checked with `az account list` => `IsDefault=True`). The issue seems related to the location of `rg-vnets`, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a network card in a different region to the vNet/Subnet it is going to be attached to, they need to be in the same region. Because you are not specifying the location in your Azure CLI command it is taking the location of the resource group, west europe, causing this issue.

Comment: Hm, but then the following should work right? `az network nic create --name nicfoo --subnet default --vnet-name vnet-switzerland-north --location switzerlandnorth --resource-group rg-foo` but it also results in a `BadRequestError`. Both `rg-foo` and `vnet-switzerland-north` are @`switzerlandnorth`. The only special thing is that the vnet is held by a resource-group (`rg-vnets`) which is in west-europe

Comment: Also when using Azure PowerShell it works.. see my updated question

Comment: The command your running should work, I would look at raising a bug in the Azure CLI repo